# SQL Server message 3154 Server 2005 to 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

So a week ago I walked into a new job where they are migrating SQL Server from version 2005 to 2008 and later to 2012.

We have a great migration plan, been here done this before, like 8 years ago so no sweat. Well it comes time to move the databases backup files from one.

So I run into the error 3154 where it says:

> 'the database backup belongs to an existing database.'

or:

> the backupfiles ... need to be Restored with MOVE ...

So.. sometimes it work, and sometimes it does not. I have tried more than a few versions of the script, I have deleted databases, created new ones, read a lot of similar stuff. Nothing consistent seems to work.

Pretty much did all this. I fear I'm looking at the nuke option.

[Error 3154 while restoring a backup using WITH REPLACE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44967/error-3154-while-restoring-a-backup-using-with-replace)

Any other ideas?

Comment: If you could replace the flavor text with a little more detail it would help massively. Like the actual error message instead of the the blahs?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in passing in the answers to the linked question, `RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH REPLACE` will replace the existing database. However, by default, the files will use the same directory path and filename as they did when the original database was backed up. If you already have files with that name at that path, or if the path (especially the drive letter) doesn't exist, then the `REPLACE` will fail - and is likely to generate an error like you describe.

In your script, use the `WITH MOVE` options to tell SQL Server to rename/relocate the database's files when it does the restore:

```
RESTORE DATABASE new_db_name 
-- .... rest of your command, up to WITH
   WITH REPLACE
       ,MOVE 'data_logical_name' TO 'X:\New\PathTo\Data\new_datafile_physical_name.mdf'
       ,MOVE 'log_logical_name' TO 'Z:\New\PathTo\Log\new_logfile_physical_name.ldf'
       -- comma, then remaining WITH options
```

If you run `SELECT * ON sys.database_files` (from within your database), you can see the current logical names and actual physical names for your database files.

If that's not convenient at this point (for instance, if the original database has already been removed, or if the backup is from servers that aren't immediately available), run:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM FILE = 'Q:\backup\file_path_and_name.bak'
```

This will tell you both what the logical file names are, and where the datafiles would be written by default. If those locations exist, and files with the same name do not exists, you can choose not to `MOVE` the files. Otherwise, you'll need to.

**Also**: When taking a backup to move to a new system, make sure that you write to a backup file that does not already exist - if you don't, you can wind up with multiple backups in the file, which complicates the restore process (at the very least). This was also mentioned in the post you point to.

If you have additional error messages beyond the ones noted, there may of course be other reasons why the `RESTORE`s are failing.

UPDATE: Make sure to specify all files using the full path to the file (as in my examples above); if you only use a file name, SQL Server may not be looking for the file in the place you'd expect.

I would only copy backups from the old system over to the new explicitly to be restored onto the new system. Once the databases on the new system are set-up, you should set up the backups for them. Don't intermingle the two sets of backups; diffs or tlog backups from one system can't be used with full backups from the other.

Comment: Thanks, pretty much have tried all that, wanted to keep the .mdf file name the same vs changing name entirely. I did get one of the offending .bak files to work by appending a a '1' to it. But now have to rename the .bak file in the 'master' table.....

Comment: Hold on a second - I've been under the assumption you were having issues restoring the backups that were taken on the original system. Are you actually having problems taking backups on the new system? Or are you trying to copy over the backups from the old system and use them as backups for the new system?

Comment: Backups from an old system moving to a new . Server 2005 to 2008

Comment: If you ran a `RESTORE` using a file named "ABC.bak", and that failed; and you changed the file name to "ABC1.bak", changed the `RESTORE` command to use the name "ABC1.bak" (making no other changes), and it succeeded, then some thing is truly weird. Are you always using the full path to the file when specifying the file names?

Comment: Also, see update - make sure you aren't intermingling the backups from the old system (only good for restoring the old system's DBs to the new system), and any backups you're taking on the new system.