# I am getting error while restoring FileGroup on SQl server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have create two filegroup FG1 and FG2.
and i have create one table student and associated with FG1. and i have created backup for FG1 with Test.bak file .

now i wanted to restore the Test.bak 
[image]
[image]

i am getting error like attached screen ..please advise

regard's
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

The database engine thinks you're trying to perform a [piecemeal restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/piecemeal-restores-sql-server) using the UI.  This is the formal name of restoring individual filegroups.  Sadly, it requires you restore the entire database to maintain transactional consistency (which I don't think you want to do in your scenario) and since you're not overwriting the database (as identified by [Pinal Dave's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/180018/39083)), you're getting this error.

If you're only trying to restore that one table, you've got a couple of options available, as follows:

1. You can restore the database as a different name and then copy the data from the restored copy into the working copy.
2. You can store that table in a different database and if you need to revert that table, restore the database it's contained within.  Of **note**, you are unable to maintain Referential Integrity between tables stored in different databases without some trickery (e.g. [Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452132/add-foreign-key-relationship-between-two-databases)).  This may not be a problem now, but it could crop up issues in the future, so just be aware of this if you do separate out this table into a different database.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to restore your backup with REPLACE command.

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks
FROM DISK = 'C:\BackupAdventureworks.bak'
WITH REPLACE
```

You can read more about it here: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/27/sql-server-fix-error-3154-the-backup-set-holds-a-backup-of-a-database-other-than-the-existing-database/

Comment: From the screenshot, the `REPLACE` option was selected when OP tried to restore.

Comment: Good Point. I suggest, please try this out with T-SQL if possible to OP.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `WITH REPLACE` while using the `RESTORE` command.
- `DROP` the older database which is conflicting and restore again using `RESTORE` command.

You should use `WITH REPLACE` and in general avoid using the point-and-click thingies in Management Studio - they're inflexible and often have bugs.

General Script:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Database_name
FROM DISK = 'c:\MSSQL\test.bak'
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'test' TO 'e:\MSSQL\test.mdf',
MOVE 'test_log' TO 'f:\MSSQL\test.ldf';
```

Check this link: [Error 3154 while restoring a backup using WITH REPLACE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44967/error-3154-while-restoring-a-backup-using-with-replace)